# swf movie over a html page (posh popup)

Tags: html, flash, popup, loader

I looking to hack something like this:

**[An example](http://www.menlotravel.com/)** >> Just click on "Start PicLens Lite Slideshow PicLens".

Did you see how the swf/flash loads on top of the normal page?
Im looking to do that **:-D**

If there is some code out there the **better** otherwise any tips or hits are welcome.

Thanks lots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at javascript tools like [Shadowbox](http://mjijackson.com/shadowbox/) that can load any types of elements into a box above the site.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [lightbox effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)).  Just set your content to your flash object and use a lightbox sans borders.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a framework such as Mootools or jQuery I'd suggest a lightbox clone that uses them (e.g. [Milkbox](http://reghellin.com/milkbox/) or [MediaBox Advanced](http://iaian7.com/webcode/mediaboxAdvanced) for for Mootools).